# I can not use Python modules on the parameters in my function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create this function in Python (3.9):

```
def format_name(f_name, l_name):
    f_name.title()
    l_name.title()
```

where f_name and l_name are going to be user inputs. However when trying to create the function the title() does not work, and also does not autocomplete, kind of as in Python does not recognize it, and this goes for all commands that I try to use on the parameters. How can I fix this?

If it matters, I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

Comment: It's completely normal that you can't call `foo.title()`, unless `foo` has a data type that has a method named `title`.

Comment: ...if `title` is a _function_ (which is different from a "module"), then you'd want to call `title(f_name)` to invoke it.

Comment: Are ```f_name``` and ```l_name``` classes?

Comment: What type of objects are `f_name` and `l_name`? Are you prompting for user input? I don't see a prompt for user input in your question.

Comment: Anyhow -- a good place to start towards having a well-formed question is building a [mre] -- code that's complete enough to reproduce the problem without any changes or additions; your `title` function is very much a change or addition.

Comment: Forgive me for making a bad post, I am quite new to programming and do not quite yet know all the correct etiquette. @ebllg answered my question, but thank you all for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want better code completion, you may want to use type hints. Try modifying your function's signature as follows:

```
def format_name(f_name: str, l_name: str)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the fix to my problem.

Comment: You are welcome @Raz. If it helped you, would you mind marking it as accepted answer?

Comment: Of course @ebllg! I am new, so I did not know this option existed. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is not intended to fix the code but rather to find the auto-complete problem Python in Visual Studio Code
you can use

### extension python visual studio code

go to:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: The question was intended to fix the code, and @ebllg found the solution. The post is badly worded, sorry about that. Autocomplete did not work because the code was wrong.